# WooCommerce - Sort products by top earner

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to list the top 4 products that have made the most money in the last 30 days.  There's plugins to show the most popular itmes, but they are sorted by the number of sales instead of the amount earned.  I've been trying to work with the code in the plugin:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
    'post_status'           => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'posts_per_page'        => $per_page,
    'meta_key'              => 'total_sales',
    'orderby'               => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_query'            => array(
        array(
            'key'       => '_visibility',
            'value'     => array( 'catalog', 'visible' ),
            'compare'   => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
```

Because I don't really know what I'm doing, I tried to jam in the code from WooCommerce's dashboard (replacing the orderby line) in hopes that it would work:

```
'data' => array(
    '_product_id' => array(
        'type'            => 'order_item_meta',
        'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
        'function'        => '',
        'name'            => 'product_id'
    ),
    '_line_total' => array(
        'type'            => 'order_item_meta',
        'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
        'function'        => 'SUM',
        'name'            => 'order_item_total'
    )
),
'order_by'     => 'order_item_total DESC',
'group_by'     => 'product_id',
```

It shows me some products, but it's not the top earners.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Using WP 4.1.5

Answer (score -1):

Use the API:

1. http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/
2. http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/

that way is there are changes to the DB, you always will get the same data.